# Calling constructor from subclass

Tags: java

I am new to java and I having problem with my code.I am trying to call a constructor of superclass from subclass's constructor.Although I can do it by **super**,but I am trying to do with other method by making a object of superclass in subclass's constructor that will call `Class A constructor`.

```
class A
{
    private int x;

    A()
    {
        System.out.println("INISDE A");
    }

    A(int h)
    {
        System.out.println("a");
        x = h;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    int g, add;

    B(int j, int h)
    {
        A a = new A(h);
        g = j;
        add = g + h;
    }

    void add()
    {
        System.out.println("SUM" + add);
    }
}

public class Ja
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        B v = new B(1, 2);
        v.add();
    }
}
```

The problem is I am getting output

```
INISDE A
a
SUM3
```

Instead of

```
a
SUM3
```

It means that it is also using the `A()` .But why? I have given parameters to it

Comment: I would really recommend you to use an IDLE with code formatting.

Comment: ... and use meaningful names.

Comment: Where's the fun in that ?!?

Comment: @Jon Skeet.I would add Meaningful names.Sorry for this time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
B(int j,int h) {
   A a=new A (h);
   g=j;
   add=g+h;    
}
```

instantiates the superclass via `A()` and *then* creates a new instance of `A` (using the single-argument constructor) separate to that underlying `B`. I suspect you really want:

```
B(int j,int h) {
   super(h);
   g=j;
   add=g+h;    
}
```

to instantiate your superclass correctly.

Comment: Yes i use super .but i was experimenting

Answer (score 3):

To call the superclass constructor you should use super(...).
So your B class constructor must look like this

```
B(int j,int h) {
  super(h);
  g=j;
  add=g+h;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your code correctly, it's because you haven't specified which A constructor you want to use in your B constructor. So by default, your B constructor will call your no-args A constructor. It's like a call to super() is implied as the first line in your B constructor.

I don't know what you're trying to do with the instance of A inside your B constructor, but you probably want super(h) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned above al lyou need to do is use super(h) instead of creating a new variable. However, I will add that you really should not use just simple letters like this to name variables. Try and use constructive names that give readers information about what is happening. It also makes it a lot easier to keep track of what's going on inside your code. Very common for beginners to do, but when you have a class A and variable a, it gets confusing. Trying using simple names such as TestClass, and fields like firstField, if you cant think of any other name.